# Set my IP to show from China

Tags: configuration

How can I force the Tor showed only that my IP is from China? Was once an option (atlas globe and countries), now I have no idea where and how to set it up so that Tor indicate in which country I find myself doing it at random.

Regards

Answer (score 3):

You can choose which node as your exit , but there is no exit node located in mainland China.

Add the following line in your torrc:

ExitNodes {hk}

You can find more information on Tor website: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the previous response, there does not appear to be any exit node based in China. Looking at the network map in Validia, there are presently about 15 exit nodes in Hong Kong.

If a HK-based IP address won't suffice, you may do well to consider finding a Chinese-based proxy using proxychains, so the chain becomes Tor > Chinese Proxy. Alternatively, you could configure Tor to connect through an SSH tunnel or VPN. In all instances, your final IP would be one located in mainland China.